# Jquery: simple selector does not work, ignoring parent element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a simple piece of HTML, that I retrieve via AJAX.
It looks like this:

```
<div id="hiddencontact">
    <form id="hiddenform"></form>
</div>
```

So, that's stored in the 'data' variable.

Now I try to run this:

```
$('#hiddencontact', data);
```

But it does not work. I do not get the div.

This, however, does work, and returns the form to me:

```
$('#hiddenform', data);
```

Why is that? Why is the first element being ignored?

Btw: I'm using jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the first element being ignored?

because the root node of `data` is `#hiddencontact` itself. So you cannot find it as a nested element

With `$('#hiddencontact', data);` you're looking for an element nested in `data`: it would be like searching for `$(data).find('#hiddencontact')`

Comment: Aha, the problem was that multiple elements where returned, so besides #hiddencontact were a few others. I just wrapped everything up inside a regular div and it works perfectly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this `$(data);` and you'll get the whole div